# Data model from Datastore to Firestore native

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to migrate a few plugins that use `DS` to `FS` and I was wondering on the data structure.  In my `DS` I am utilizing `ancestors`

so the top level `Kind` is `Users` and any other `Kinds` consist of ancestors from `Users`. E.g. Kind `Products` has ancestor `Key(Users,'UUID')`.

In `Firestore` world would it be structure looks like this:

```
1. Users(Collections):
   {userID:...
   ...
   so on},
   {...},
   ...list of users

2. Products(Collections).User-1(Doc)
                           Subcollections{...list of product docs belonging to User1}
                        .User-2(Doc)
                           Subcollections{...list of product docs belonging to User2}
```

`Users` and `Products` top-level collections.

or

this structure would be better:

```
+ Users (collection)
 * user_1 (document)
     - name: "Blah"
     - last: "Blah"
     + Product (subcollection)
         * product_1 (document)
             - title: "blah...."
             - vendor: "blah..."
             + Product_variants (subcollection)
                 * product_1 (document)
                     - name: "..."
                     - price: "..."
                 * product_2 (document)
                     - name: "..."
                     - price: "..."
         * product_2 (document)
             - title: "blah...."
             - vendor: "blah..."
             + Product_variants (subcollection)
                 * product_1 (document)
                     - name: "..."
                     - price: "..."
                 * product_2 (document)
                     - name: "..."
                     - price: "..."
```

Is there a better way to handle this structure? Also concern from an action update perspective which simpler would be? I am trying to understand tradeoffs between `update` vs. `query`. For example if I have users that have more than `100K` products and getting events on updates/deletes/... is there downside of that structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update: As of May, 2019, Cloud Firestore now supports [collection group queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query).**

You can now structure the data either way and still be able to query across users.

**Original Answer**

If I'm understanding correctly, you're asking about the trade-offs of having flat collections vs subcollections.

As far as updates are concerned, there aren't any material differences. One thing to look out for is if you have fields that cluster around a single value. For example, with flat collections if products had an update-time field then by default you'd be limited to 500 updates/second across all users. With products nested within users you're limited to 500 updates/second per user. However, with flattened collections you can work around this by disabling the default single-field index on update-time and creating a composite index on (user, update-time). Once you do that, these are equivalent.

The real difference comes down to which queries are possible. In Firestore as it exists today, you can only query within a subcollection tree. So for example, if you wanted to search for products from a specific title or vendor, you'd only be able to search within a single user.

If you flatten the collections such that products is a top-level collection, you can query across users.

Note that collection group queries are a feature we're developing that will remove this restriction. Once that's launched you'll be able to structure the data either way and still be able to query across users.

Comment: Thanks Gil!  I was a bit confused with flat collections. Also on the limits of 20k fields and max size of the doc ~1m.